# Direct Credit Card payment using Classic Api in PayPal

Tags: c#, paypal

I just want to know whether `Classic API` for doing `Direct Recurring Payment using Credit Card` in paypal is available in India or not.

Bcoz...i have made application using `REST API` but in `Account Eligibility` it is shown as `Direct credit cards is not enabled for live transactions` they are allowing recurring in sandbox account but not in Live..

My question is can it be done using Classic Api rather than Rest API in India ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Payments Pro is only available for US, UK, or Canada accounts.

Comment: Ohh...So is there any alternative for doing Recurring Direct Credit Card Payment in paypal

Comment: Actually, adding recurring payments to Pro is additional feature, too.  You're not going to be able to do it with an account in India, unfortunately, but you could set up profiles with Express Checkout.

Comment: Actually,My company has US Account so using that can i use that ?

Comment: Yes, if you have a US account that should be just fine.  Just apply for the US Payments Pro and make sure to login with that account and you should be good.